# How to set height of cell in grouped style table?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have made a table with two types of custom cells using interface builder:

[image]

Everything works fine, except lower cell's height is same as cell above it. It has everything i put - UIImageView etc...

So I was thinking if it is not possible to change cell height when table style is grouped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath{

   if (indexPath.row == 1) {

   return 100;
   }

   return 44;
}
```

Comment: Nice and clean.  I try to avoid elses if I can help it.

Answer (score 2):

We can use UITableview Delegate Methods :

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   if (indexPath.row == 1)
      {
          return 60;
      }
   else
      {
          return 44;
      }
 }
```

Comment: His second cell needs specific height, so its indexPath.row == 1 ;-), "else" is not necessary because you return anyway if indexPath.row == 1 is true.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use this

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{
    return 75.0f;

}

it is use full for me.